# How to simply center equations using eqnarray*?

Tags: equations, amsmath

So I have this code here:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 \\
   (x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 = w^2 \\
    x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 = (x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

As you can see, I get the following result:

[image]

My problem is that I want to 'center' all those equations, so that they 'look nice'. What that means is that I dont necessarily want the equal signs to be alligned. I want the entire thing to be centered, evenly, so that it looks pleasing to the eye. Basically, if the top two equations were moved to the left somehow, then that would be 'centered'.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: [Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks for the link, I do not have time to run through it right at this moment, but is there a main reason for it to be avoided though?

Comment: From the TOC: (1) Spacing inconsistency (2) Eqnarray might overwrite equation numbers (3) labels can get mixed up.

Comment: comment on tags: `eqnarray` has nothing to do with `amsmath` (or vice versa), so `amsmath` isn't a suitable tag for the question as asked.  i'm leaving it, though, since the most logical answer -- `gather` -- *does* use an environment from `amsmath`.  check the `amsmath` user's guide (`texdoc amsldoc`) for the environments that *are* supported.

Answer (score 19):

For any kind of display math you should load the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 \\
   (x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 = w^2 \\
    x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 = (x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason gather* was not autocompleting and when I typed it out it didnt work, (before I asked the question on here), but it appears to work now... murphy's law I guess.

Comment: I take it from the number of upvotes that gather > eqnarray ?... (Noob here).

Comment: The standard `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` really make rather poor spacing so in almost all cases you should use the AMS alignments. But especially here for a sequence of unaligned equations LaTeX has no direct support for that, but that is _precisely_ what `gather` is designed to do.

Comment: Great. I was just warming up to eqnarray* too. >< Thanks though! I am learning.

Comment: So what to do when a journal requires you not to load extra packages?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    &x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 \\
    &(x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 = w^2 \\
    &x + (y - 2)^4 = w^2 = (x  - 9)^2 + y_2^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Nice! Worked great. Is there a way to arbitrarily push one equation to be 'lower' than the one above him by any chance?

Comment: @Mohammad: The double-backslash ` \\ ` takes an optional argument which is the amount of extra space to skip.

Comment: Ah right. >< I am still a noob. Thanks though!

Comment: @Mohammad This sort of looks OK but is abusing the `eqnarray` environment syntax which is designed to always have three columns with the centre column being the operator.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. Try using a summation symbol and you'll see why.